# Align HTML input date picker to right

Tags: css, html

i was not able to align the date picker comes input type="datetime-local" to the right side of the input element   [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/oep40uhm/)

```css
input{
  width:400px;
}
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" class="dateTime" name="starttime" id="startTime" step="2">
```

This is the current  view:

[image: This is the current view]

my requirement is to position that datepicker square to the right side without using javascript

expected result below::

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this code this will help you.. I only use css for input: text-align:right.

```css
input{
  width:400px;
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" class="dateTime" name="starttime" id="startTime" step="2">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `div` tag so `datetime-local` will be on the right side of the page as you want.

So your code will be :

```
<div align="right">
<input type="datetime-local" step="2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align content of input to the right side, just use `text-align: right;` in css.
I don't think it's possible to align calendar to the right ... But I also recommend you to use some js datetimepicker because of the [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=datetime-local)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achive that, because you are trying to change a default browser property and every browser have custom css for distinct input types.

So if you wanna achieve that what you're have to use a custom datepicker an then do whatever you wanna do, and align it anywhere.

[Here you have some examples](https://www.cssscript.com/tag/date-picker/)

Comment: And other reason to use custom datepicker is, for example, the input type datetime-local is not supported on Firefox.